# How do you achieve this round border seperation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a page like this and I've tried border radius but i just can't get it right. My border becomes too round and always looks off when the middle portion of the div starts to see the effects of border radius.

Pic below of What I want

[image]

How would I achieve this?

What I have

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100vh; padding: 0px; background-color: white">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src="http://cdn.homedsgn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Flyway-View-House-00-1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid green; height: 100vh">
            sign up field
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.image-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-container img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you also have the option to use an extra class and a pseudo to hide partially the image:

```css
.image-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-container img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.rounded {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.rounded:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:-15vh;
  bottom:-15vh;
  right:0;
  width:30vw;
  border-radius:0 50% 50%  0/ 100%;
  box-shadow: 
      15vh 0 white, 
      inset -3px 0 2px white /* inset is optionnal and buggy at screen .. tiny gap shows image in between both shadows */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" rounded hidden-xs col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100vh; padding: 0px; background-color: white">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src="http://cdn.homedsgn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Flyway-View-House-00-1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid green; height: 100vh">
            sign up field
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! this looks great. Could I ask what you even did?? I don't quite understand the before portion

Comment: @james the `:before` creates a virtual boxe that i layed over its parent and made it much taller.  I applied to it a radius to curve it on the right, then added a plain white shadow going to the right too to hide parts of the image. to avoid the pseudo element to be drawn on top of other element, i made the parent hidding overflow.

Answer (score 1):

well you could start with this :) off course different browser have different css for border

```css
        .image-container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .image-container img{
            height: 100%;
            width: 800px;
            object-fit: cover;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
            border-top-right-radius: 323px;
        }
        
        .box{
        
            border: 1px solid green;
    width: 500px;
    background: white;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 90px;
        
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100vh; padding: 0px; background-color: white">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src="http://cdn.homedsgn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Flyway-View-House-00-1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 box" style="border: 1px solid green; height: 100vh">
            sign up field
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3. I'm not sure if you're seeing the same thing as I am but it looks really messed up for me

Comment: ok i never used bootstrap before. you dont see the right result in stackoverflow because im using absolute position. so try to copy the html and css to an html file an se the result. for carved corners you use   border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;  border-top-right-radius: 323px;